# How to group rows with same ID but different values in two columns into a single row the different values as columns in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset that looks like this:

`df = pd.DataFrame([[1,1,5,4],[1,1,6,3]], columns =['date','site','chemistry','measurement']) df`

I'm looking to transform this dataset so that the values in the chemistry and measurement columns become separate columns and the repeated values in the other columns become a single row like this:

`new_df = pd.DataFrame([[1,1,4,3]], columns=['date','site','5','6']) new_df`

I've tried some basic things like df.transpose() pd.pivot() but this doesn't get me what I need.

The pivot is closer but still not the format I'm looking for.

I'm imagining there's a way to loop through the dataframe to this but I'm not sure how to do it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please see [how to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Comment: Please [edit] to include sample input and expected output in the text of your question, not as a link or image, so that we can reproduce it. See [How to make good pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 df.set_index(['date','site','chemistry'])['measurement'].unstack().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
chemistry  date  site  5  6
0             1     1  4  3
```